# KeyError:'1' in python

Tags: python, keyerror

Here is my code:

```py
 myDict = {}
    lemma_word_pair = OrderedDict()
    for line in original_text:        
        if len(line)>10:
            myDict['1'] = {"src":line,"tag":"P"}
            postdata = {
                    'data':json.dumps({'1':myDict['1']}),
                    'type':'X',
                    'ue':'UTF-8'
                    }
            data = urllib.urlencode(postdata)
            response = eval(urllib2.urlopen("http://fanyi.youdao.com/web2/index.do",data=data).read())
            word_count = len(response['data']['1'])
```

and then this is the output:

```
  File "Luoke.py", line 41, in extract_and_reduce
    word_count = len(response['data']['1'])
KeyError: '1'
```

How could I solve the problem? I have tried many kinds of methods on Stackoverflow but none of them works.

Comment: For a start, provide a [mcve] in your question, i.e. code that anyone can take and run to reproduce the issue. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Looks like the response doesn't contain what you're expecting. As it is, your code would work if it was something like `{"data": {"1": ...}}`. Also, do not use `eval`, and never EVER with something you got from the internet.

Comment: have you tried the code by removing quotes of '1' to make it 1?

Comment: ***DO NOT USE `eval()` TO INTERPRET CONTENT YOU RECEIVE FROM THE INTERNET.*** You are effectively asking strangers to run any code they like on your computer, possibly including viruses or spyware. It also *isn't even correct* for reading arbitrary JSON data; for example, it will not handle `null`, `true` or `false` correctly (those have no special meaning in Python and will be understood as just variable names - the Python equivalents are `None`, `True` and `False` respectively).

Comment: Anyway, please try to [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). For example, why do you think `response['data']['1']` *should* work? What does the documentation say about how the `response` data will look? Why should it have those keys? Does it *actually* have those keys? What do you see if you try displaying the entire `response`? What are the `response['data'].keys()`? I am assuming here that you *understand* the error message - yes?